# How to solve Hoffman & Kunze exercise 8, section 5.3

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A be a 3 X 3 matrix over the field of complex numbers.
>
> We form the
>   matrix $xI-A$ with polynomial entries, the $i,j$ entry of this matrix being the
>   polynomial $\delta_{ij}x - A_{ij}$
>
> a) If f=$\det (xl-A)$,show that f is a monic polynomial
>   of degree 3.
>
> b)If we write $f = (x-c_1)(x-c_2)(x-c_3)$
>   with complex numbers $c_1,c_2,c_3$, prove that $c_1+c_2+c_3=$ trace (A) and $c_1c_2c_3$=det A .

Let's say I already wrote part a as:

det(x$I$-A)= $(x-a_{11})(x^2-a_{33}x-a_{22}x+a_{22}a_{33}-a_{23}a_{32})+a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33}-a_{21}x-a_{23}a_{31)}-a_{13}(a_{21}a_{32}+a_{31}x-a_{22}a_{31})$

Note that I wrote A with entries $a_{ij}$, where i is the row and j is the column.

How could I do the part b?
I guess I have to assume that each c is the root of f, but I do not know how to proceed

Comment: Kindly attach the image of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$ f(x) = \det (xI - A) = (x - c_1)(x - c_2) (x - c_3),$$ then
$$  c_1 c_2 c_3 = - f(0) = - \det (0I - A) = \det A .$$

Now suppose that
$$ f(x) = x^3 + b_2 x^2 + b_1 x + b_0$$
is the polynomial expansion of $f(x)$.

Then $$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = -b_2.$$

And from the calculation in your question, 
$$b_2 = - (a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33}) = - {\rm tr } A.$$

[Alternatively, let's compute the characteristic polynomial from scratch, focusing only on extracting the $x^2$ coefficient:
\begin{align} \det (xI - A) & = \det \begin{bmatrix} x - a_{11} & - a_{12} & - a_{13} \\
-a_{21} & x - a_{22} & - a_{23} \\ - a_{31} & -a_{32} & x -a_{33} \end{bmatrix}
\\ & = (x - a_{11})(x - a_{22})(x - a_{33}) + {\rm terms \ linear \ in \ } x \\
& = x^3 - (a_{11} + a_{22}  + a_{33}) x^2 + {\rm terms \ linear \ in \ } x.\end{align}
]

Comment: Sorry for not getting it, but how does $b_2=-(a_{11}+a_{22}+a_{33})=−trA.$ Help me?

Comment: @Juju9704 Look at your expression: $det(xI-A)= (x-a_{11})(x^2-a_{33}x-a_{22}x+a_{22}a_{33}-a_{23}a_{32})+a_{12}(a_{21}a_{33}-a_{21}x-a_{23}a_{31)}-a_{13}(a_{21}a_{32}+a_{31}x-a_{22}a_{31})$.

Comment: If you expand this out, then the coefficient of $x^2$ is $-(a_{11} + a_{22} + a_{33})$.